# Git installation on FreeBSD 5

Tags: git, freebsd, installation-package

I am running FreeBSD 5.3-RELEASE and I need to install Git on it, need to pull from a remote git server.

Has anyone done this exercise for FreeBSD 5.3? Or some really old FreeBSD?

Comment: I think it's a bit old to have a package for it, but it should compile from source just fine. https://github.com/gitster/git/zipball/master

Comment: builds just fine and runs great

Answer (score 1):

the build from source is the correct thing to do. Works without a hitch